# How to unnest an array for supply a sequence of arguments?

Tags: arrays, postgresql

PostgreSQL 9.2 works with,

```
 SELECT Format('%s %s!', 'Hello', 'world');
```

But I need something like

```
 SELECT Format('%s %s!', array['Hello', 'world'] );
```

or, more specifically, I need some  `convertToArgs`,

```
 SELECT Format('%s %s!', convertToArgs( array['Hello', 'world'] ) );
```

---

NOTE: the real problem is generic, with any number of itens (in the array and compatible placeholders)

```
  SELECT Format(template, convertToArgs( values ) );
```

Comment: There is no Postgres version "9.X". Quoting the [official versioning policy](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/): `A major release is numbered by increasing either the first or second part of the version number, e.g. 9.1 to 9.2.` A consequence of this inaccuracy: pozs gave an answer (hinting `VARIADIC`) that works for 9.3 but nor for 9.2 or earlier ...

Comment: Ok, sorry, I see... editing question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is called [`VARIADIC`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-VARIADIC-FUNCTIONS) arguments.

You can call a `VARIADIC` parameter with an array too, if you prepend the `VARIADIC` keyword:

```
SELECT format('%s %s!', VARIADIC ARRAY['Hello', 'world']);
```

**EDIT**: as [@ErwinBrandstetter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23219776/how-to-unnest-an-array-for-supply-a-sequence-of-arguments/35852065#comment35852065_23221583) pointed out, this will won't work in 9.2. Not because `VARIADIC` arguments call, nor `format()` is unsupported. According to docs `concat`, `concat_ws` and `format` just cannot be called in that way (before 9.3 - beside the fact, that `pg_get_functiondef` reports it variadic in 9.2 too). User defined functions *can* be called this way in 9.2 too.

Comment: OPS, I voted but there are an error when run this SELECT: "few arguments" error.

Comment: Works here with Postgres 9.3. `VARIADIC` calls are in the docs from 8.4. `format()` are in the docs from 9.0. Are you sure you ran this exact query?

Comment: hum... My postgreSQL is not 9.3, is 9.2.3... Well I must wait. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `ERROR: too few arguments for format SQL state: 22023` if that is your error message even after using the `VARIADIC` keyword properly, that means you supplied more placeholders in the first parameter in the `format()` call than you have in your array. f.ex: `SELECT format('%s %s!', VARIADIC ARRAY['Hello']);`

Comment: @PeterKrauss: The [manual for 9.3 states](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/functions-string.html): `The concat, concat_ws and format functions are variadic ...`. The same is *not* true for 9.2 or earlier.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter yeah, just tested. However `pg_get_functiondef` reports it variadic in 9.2 too. Weird. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d41d8/2360

Answer (score 0):

```
select format('%s!', array_to_string(array['Hello', 'world'], ' '));
    format    
--------------
 Hello world!
```

Comment: Sorry... good ideia for workaround in the example, but is not a solution to the problem. My database use `format(t,a)`, both variables, `a` with variable `array_length(a,1)`, and `t` with compatible placeholders.

Comment: @Peter Can you use PL/pgSQL?